# How can I get Rspec to run all tests nested under a folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I like to run my Rspec tests with Spork running in a separate tab. I usually run my tests using `rspec spec`, by which I intend to say "search recursively and run everything in the `spec` folder."

I've recently realized that this does not actually run all my tests. I now have a spec file in `spec/requests` which isn't being run. I know this because I've edited one of the tests to raise an error, and run the following:

- `rspec spec` - no error raised.
- `rspec spec/requests` - still no error raised, and `0 examples, 0 failures`!
- `rspec spec/requests/my_controller.rb` - **bingo**. `17 examples, 1 failure` and the failure has my error message.

**Why isn't Rspec finding all my test files? Is this a matter of configuration, or do I need to use a different command to run my tests?**

I need to run all my tests at once to ensure that I'm not introducing regressions.

(Not using Spork makes no difference, by the way.)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Rspec **should** already look recursively through the directory you named and find all tests. Note however, that it's looking for files ending in `_spec.rb`. Maybe some of your files are not named correctly?

If you need to be more specific about which files it should find, you can also use the `--pattern` option. For example: `rspec --pattern spec/requests/*_spec.rb`. (Option `--pattern` is equal to `-P`. Taken from `rspec --help`)

Answer (score 4):

you can create a rake task

```
desc "Run PCMag tests"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new('test') do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = ["-Ilib","--format documentation","--color"]
  t.pattern = ['spec/test/*.rb']
end
```

Then execute command rake test.

Above command will execute all .rb tests under folder 'test'

Please check following link for more details.

http://testautomationarchives.blogspot.in/2013/10/rspec-rake-framework-in-ruby-with.html